# Issue with Python 3 Imports when using a Shell script

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I have the following scenario:

- A Python3 Package (meross_iot) installed through pip and located in
  ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
- A Python script (meross_electricity.py) that imports from this package: `from meross_iot.controller.mixins.electricity import ElectricityMixin`
- A shell script (launcher.sh) that is meant to be a wrapper so that the .py script is run at startup:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  # launcher.sh
  # navigate to home directory, then to this directory, then execute python script, then back home

  cd /
  cd home/pi/Documents
  sudo python meross_electricity.py
  cd /
  ```

If I simply execute the .py file everything works as expected, imports done, etc. If I try to run the .sh script I get the following error:

```
pi@home:~/Documents $ ./launcher.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "meross_electricity.py", line 4, in <module>
    from meross_iot.controller.mixins.electricity import ElectricityMixin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'meross_iot'
```

Can someone please help me solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: You have installed the package for a local user, in its home. With `sudo` you are switching to the user `root` with an other home.

Comment: /facepalm Rooky mistake. Thanks Klaus! Solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Installed package with sudo worked .

<sub>Answer based on comment by @KlausD</sub>